# How can I move a file from a Jenkins slave to a shared network location (Test automation with Java & Cucumber)

Tags: java, jenkins, automation, automated-tests, cucumber

We have a Java based Test Automation framework (using a Cucumber layer) running on a  Jenkins server. I have a Cucumber grammar that simply moves a file (an xml file) from a location within the Java project to a location on a shared network space.

It works fine when run on my local machine, but when run on the Jenkins slave it is only able to find the file within the project (using System.getProperty("user.dir")), but it cannot find the network location to send the file to.

I tried to map to the root C Drive to see if that would work but again, it only works on my local machine. The Slave can't seem to find its own C drive?

Does anyone know of a way to correctly  pass a network location to a jenkins slave so that I could move a file from the slave to a shared folder? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the Jenkins slave is running Windows? Is the user that runs Jenkins allowed to access this network location? To, your problem sounds like a setup problem that doesn't have anything to do with Cucumber. Or Jenkins. It is probably a user or OS problem.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! You're quite right! We did some investigation today, and it turns out that while the slaves *are* running windows, they are only being used by the Selenium grid to drive the web browser, and the actual code itself is being executed on the master, which is a linux server! So the new plan is to try execute a unix command from the java project, to perform the file copy operation between the server and the network folder. I'll report back and let you know if it works!